# How do i frame selected objects in non-local viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

Is it possible to frame selected objects in my viewport (see image), i mean every time a frame selected all the other non selected objects disappear? and if this is possible what is the feature name to create hotkey.

I would be very grateful for any tips, suggestions or help in this matter. Thanks Stewart[image]

Comment: "Frame Selected" ( Numpad  . ) shouldn't make anything else disappear. "Local Mode ( forward / ) "is what makes other things disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this cover your needs, but you can enable addon **Stored Views**. Located in 3D View > Sidebar (N)
From there you can save any view or camera view and switch between them.

[image]